# draw different colors on one line using core plot in ios

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have been trying to find the solution for drawing different colors on one line using Core plot. For clear understanding I have pasted the Image.I am able to drawn only one color throughout the line but wants change the line color based on the x and y values.Please let me know if I am not clear. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about Core Plot, but this can be done using Shape Layer. Should I post an answer on that?

Comment: So basically what you want is when the plotting begins, the color will be red and when it reaches end of page it would have transitioned through many colors and become green right??

Answer (score 1):

First get a `CAShapeLayer` instance with the size of your plotting area, set its `path` property to the bezier path that you want to plot.

Next get an image of the size of your plotting area, which has the colour patterns as you want. Add this to an imageview which in turn is added as subview to your plotting area.

Now set the shape layer instance to `mask` property of your imageview's layer. At this stage if you run the project, you should see the complete plotted graph with the varying colour's.

You can animate the imageview's width from 0 to width of the plotting area to get the nice plotting affect.

You can refer one of my [github project](https://github.com/adithyabhat/CircleFillAnimation) where I have used similar technique to get a fill animation.

Comment: Aditya Using the above can I draw graphs?

Comment: @Tendulkar As far as I understand your requirement, this should do it.

Comment: Ok what do you mean by image view why I am asking you is I don't have any image views or images

Comment: This is just one of the approach that will work in your situation. Image view is required to display the colored pattern image. For Eg something like http://jakubmarian.com/images/content/xor3d/colors.png You may require a different pattern.

Comment: Basically what is happening here is that, since the shape layer(with the path defined) is added as mask to your imageview's layer, only that portion of the image where there is path, is drawn.

Comment: Check out this sample project I just created https://github.com/adithyabhat/TestProjects/tree/master/ShapeLayerTest I'm just drawing a straight line, in your case you need to set the path that you want to plot.

Comment: ok thank you but here the problem is we need to get the frame for drawing the lines. So trying to get the Point which Coreplot draws the lines on Graph

Answer (score 0):

coreplot supports flexible line styles for a plot. See property CPTScatterPlot.dataLineStyle. This line style can have a fill or a gradient, which should be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I want to change the colors based on the x and y values is it possible using CPTScatterPlot.dataLineStyle?